# Objective-c saving raw text

Tags: objective-c, save

I implemented saving and loading methods in my document-based application. In the saving method, I have

```
[NSArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[self string]];
```

Where `[self string]` is a NSString.
When saving a file with just "normal content" inside of it, the contents of the file created are:

> streamtypedè@NSStringNSObject+normal content

Is there a way to store in a file just raw text?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i am new with cocoa, i don't know if this is the right way to do it or even a valid way.

But after a quick look at the documentation i found this method of NSString instances, `- (NSData *)dataUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding`

A quick try on a sample project it worked fine with:
`- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError`

So something like this might work for you:

```
- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
    return [[self string] dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There are methods inside NSString for saving in a file:

```
NSString * s = @"Foo bar";

NSError * err = NULL;
BOOL result = [s writeToFile:@"/tmp/test.txt" atomically:YES encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding  error:&err];
```

Comment: In other words, don't use NSArchiver.

Comment: Well. How I can use that method? `- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError` returns data. Where I should put the NSString method?

Comment: writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error is a method on NSString.  See the documentation.

Comment: Instead, I used `[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`. It works as expected.

Comment: By the way: NSString is a beast. I first shook my head when I saw stringWithContentsOfURL.